# A tiny template language

Tags: regex, perl, parsing

I pass a string with a "partial" SQL statement like:

```
"SELECT %FIELDS% FROM ... %ORDER% %LIMIT%"
```

Then I want to replace `%FIELDS%` either with a real list of fields (which I get from an array) or with `COUNT(*)`. Likewise I replace `%ORDER%` either with `ORDER BY ...` (which I generate) or with empty string and `%LIMIT%` with either `LIMIT ...` (which I generate) or with empty string.

I also want a way to prevent these sequences to be replaced. For example we may "turn off" replacing if percents are doubled: `%%FIELDS%%` should be not replaced with a list of fields but be replaced with literal `%FIELDS%`.

Note that I do not insist namely on this syntax. Instead of percent signs we may use some other escape syntax (for example `${FIELDS}` or `{{FIELDS}}`).

I want the most easy and (what is probably more important) most efficient way to do this.

Note that I use Perl.

Maybe, I should not invent my own template language with regexps and use Perl module `Template::Tiny`? What will be the most efficient?

Comment: The most simple approach `$s =~ s/%FIELDS%/join(",",@f)/ge;` should work here

Comment: @HåkonHægland This does not support "I also want a way to prevent these sequences to be replaced" in my question. If it could be so simple, I'd not ask how to do this

Comment: Yes.. you are right.. so after replacing `%FIELDS%` an `"%ORDER%"` string could appear, that you do not want to replace when you substitute for `%ORDER%` later?

Comment: @HåkonHægland I do not want to replace second time the result of replacement of `%FIELDS%` (even if the result of replacement contains `%ORDER%`). I also want a way to write literal `%FIELDS%` which could not be replaced (for example doubling percent signs like `%%FIELDS%%`)

Comment: Basically, in many languages, allow you to interpret your variable such as in bash `cmd=\`ls -al\`` then `eval $cmd` you will get source code `ls -al`. I think it's a same mechanism right?

Comment: If you set all your data into variables `FIELDS`, `ORDER`, `LIMIT` you can do `SELECT eval $FIELDS FROM eval ORDER eval LIMIT` something like this more easy.

Comment: @terces907 I need to process my template more than once. For this simple `eval` would not work

Comment: The problem here is not about regex but about finding a unique syntax. If you can put some example of want and don't want text then I can help you, no one know your detail, what a translated text looks like,no one can ans you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub MyReplace {
  my ($tmpl, $Hash) = @_;

  my %Hash2;
  foreach my $Key (keys %$Hash) {
    $Hash2{"%$Key%"} = $Hash->{$Key};
    $Hash2{"\\%$Key%"} = "%$Key%"; # escaped
  }

  my $re_str = "(" . (join '|', map { "\Q$_\E" } keys %Hash2) . ")";
  $tmpl =~ s/$re_str/$Hash2{$1}/g;
  return $tmpl;
}

print MyReplace('SELECT %FIELDS% FROM ... %ORDER% %LIMIT%', {FIELDS=>'a, b, c', ORDER=>'ORDER BY id', LIMIT=>''}), "\n";
print MyReplace('SELECT \\%FIELDS% FROM ... %ORDER% \\\\%LIMIT%', {FIELDS=>'a, b, c', ORDER=>'ORDER BY id', LIMIT=>''}), "\n";
```